# Extended GET SET Object

Tags: c#

```
public class ZakazkandDTO
{
    private decimal? _pcPevna;
    private decimal? _sleva;
    
    public decimal? PcPevna 
    { 
        get => _pcPevna;
        set 
        { 
            _pcPevna = value; 
            if (_pcPevna.HasValue) 
                Sleva = PcSpec = 0; 
        }
    }
    
    public decimal? Sleva 
    { 
        get => _sleva; 
        set 
        { 
            _sleva = value; 
            if (_sleva.HasValue) 
                PcPevna = null; 
        }
    }
    
    public decimal? PcSpec { get; set; }
}
```

This is my DTO object, when i try to set property PcPevna it does not work. why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because setting `PcPevna` to a value != null sets `Sleva` to 0 and its setter in turn sets `PcPevna` back to `null`.

Change the code to

```
public decimal? PcPevna {
    get => _pcPevna;
    set {
        _pcPevna = value;
        if (_pcPevna.HasValue)
            _sleva = PcSpec = 0;
    }
}

public decimal? Sleva { 
    get => _sleva;
    set {
        _sleva = value;
        if (_sleva.HasValue)
            _pcPevna = null;
    }
}
```

I.e., set the backing fields directly to avoid triggering the setters of the other properties again.